# How do I style the button in a 'file' element with jQueryUI Button?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI Button widget to style all the buttons on my pages, but the button on a 'file' type input remains elusive.  How do I style this button in general, and can I somehow apply the Button widget to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a write up about styling the "browse" button (and problems therein) http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#present

Answer (score 1):

File input elements are notoriously difficult to style.

There's a workaround described on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) - check it out. I find it horribly hacky but it seems to work.

If you need more styling possibilities, you may have to look at a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org). They work in a different way however - Flash uploads the file data directly - so you may have to change the way your forms work.

Comment: +1 - the quirksmode solution is a bit hacky but it does work well.  There's a trade-off using both solutions, SWFUpload requires flash and the quirksmode solution requires JS (unless you go with the CSS only solution which doesn't show the file name/path after it's been chosen).  The upside for quirksmode is that it should gracefully degrade if JS isn't switched on.